# Remove floating keyboard once and for all

Tags: ios, magic-keyboard-ipad

I use a hardware keyboard (the magic keyboard) with my iPad pro. It runs iOS 16.6. Each time I use an app with a text box (such as Slack, but other apps as well), an irritating (and useless) “floating keyboard” consumes screen real estate and is distracting. Attached is a screenshot to illustrate what I am talking about.

How does one deactivate that keyboard for good? I can drag it around but I just don’t want it there at all. I have never needed it and have no use for it. It seems to simply be an annoyance.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'd hardly call this useless.  The floating keyboard quick access object is designed to do markup, emojis, alternate keyboard layouts, etc.  This also feels very familiar...did you already post this question, but weren't satisififed with the responses?

Comment: I did not post about this. So is there a way to remove it?